# how do I make an rx demultiplexor?

Tags: rx-java

I am new to Rx semantics. specifically I'm learning it with RxJava.

I want to write a de-multiplexer using rx semantics.

details:
I have an observable that emits events of type T.
type T has an attribute of type K, obtainable by executing some T->K function "getAttr" on it.
I would like to register observers, each interested in T events with a different "getAttr" result value.
the value of "getAttr" should be matched by using equals() (meaning mutually exclusive observers).

seems to me there should already be some basic building block that does this kind of thing, But I didn't find any.

Any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: You'll have to give an example of what you're after.

Comment: I don't understand the whole idea of your question, but it sounds like you should look at [groupBy](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/groupby.html) .
Using it, you can forward the incoming values, based on their getAttr method to different GroupedObservables, and at the end, you can attach different Observers to these GroupedObservables, using their keys. Something like that...

Comment: Sounds you probably want something like `observable.filter(o -> o.getAttr() == "foo").subscribe(...); observable.filter(o -> o.getAttr() == "bar").subscribe(...); ...`. Depending on the temperature of the observable you might also want to publish/connect/refcount it first..

Answer (score 0):

Given `Observable<T> observable`, this code gives you an observable for a specific `K value` of the attribute:

```
Observable<T> observable = ...
final K value = ...
final Function<T, K> toAttribute = ...

Observable<GroupedObservable<K, T>> grouped = 
    observable.groupBy(element -> toAttribute.apply(element))

Observable<T> filtered = 
    .filter(groupedObservable -> groupedObservable.getKey().equals(value))
    .flatMap(observable -> observable)
```